# Multiple contacts in Task is not showing up in query result

Tags: apex, tasks, activities, activity-settings

I have enabled "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" Activity setting and I am able to add multiple contacts to name field from task layout. But when I am querying from developer console the result is returning only the primary contact not. Even in Account layout under open Activities I can see the primary contact.

What else setting I need to enable to view and fetch all the contacts assigned in name field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [EventRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) and [TaskRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm) objects to locate additional contacts related to tasks and events.

Comment: When I am trying to insert Task object from Apex it is taking only one contact and so creating only one TaskRelation entry. How to assign multiple contacts which internally should create those many TaskRelation entries?